# Checking for NaN in clojure

Tags: clojure, floating-point, nan

I have some algorithm which for one reason or another spits out NaNs, I would both like to just filter out these bad results for the time being, and some point later go and find out the problem.  Hence, I need to check that a value is NaN, how do I do this?

I thought I could use the trick that a NaN is the only value not equal to itself so I wrote the following function

```
(defn NaN?
  "Test if this number is nan"
  [x]
  ; Nan is the only value for which equality is false
  (false? (= x x)))
```

This works if I ask `(NaN? Double/NaN Double/NaN`).  However if the values NaN are in some data structure (as is the case), and have all ready been evaluated in some sense, then this does not work.  For instance

```
(def test Double/Nan)
(NaN? test)
```

returns false.

Comment: (number? Double/NaN) => true - hehe!

Comment: Indeed! That's what I had in my original code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with using the java static functions for these tests, try.

```
(Double/isNaN x)
```

As you've discovered NaN is not equal to anything including itself, if you want to ignore NaN values for equality you can either remove, replace (see clojure.walk/prewalk-replace) or test for them explicitly, eg.

```
(let [nan? #(and (number? %) (Double/isNaN %))
      vec-data [1 Double/NaN]
      map-data {:a 1 :b Double/NaN}]

    [;; compare vectors without NaN values
    (= (remove nan? vec-data) (remove nan? vec-data))

    ;; check that all differences in 2 maps are nan? 
    (every? nan? (mapcat vals (take 2 (clojure.data/diff map-data map-data))))])

     ;; => [true true]
```

Answer (score 3):

The following use of == did it

```
(defn NaN?
  "Test if this number is nan"
  [x]
  ; Nan is the only value for which equality is false
  (false? (== x x)))
```

And more simply we can just use Double/isNaN